# Struggling with how to incorporate a reordering of dataframe rows based on a Vector within my function

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2) for diamonds dataset
```

I'm having trouble getting my function to work. What I'm trying to do, using the diamonds dataset form ggplot2 for this example, is to dplyr::group_by "cut" and "color", then dplyr::summarise to get counts. I used rlang and purrr to output both summaries of counts into list, then rename one of the columns, and bind them with dplyr::map_df. Finally, I want to reorder the "Cut" column based on another vector called "Order". The function works until I try to incorporate the row reordering...

This might not make sense for this data, but this is just for an example and it makes sense for my real data.

Anyways, the code below works...

```
Groups<-list("cut","color")

 Groups<-Groups%>%
 map_df(function(group){

     syms<-syms(group)

     diamonds%>%
         group_by(!!!syms)%>%
         summarise(Count=n())%>%
         set_names(c("Cut","Count"))
 })
```

And next, I want to reorder the rows based on the "Order" vector, which also works.

```
Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

Groups%>%slice(match(Order, Cut))
```

However, this is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to do all this in one function, but it doesn't seem to work. I feel like I'm missing something small...

```
Fun<-function(df){

Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

Groups<-list("cut","color")

 Groups<-Groups%>%
 map_df(function(group){

     syms<-syms(group)

     df%>%
         group_by(!!!syms)%>%
         summarise(Count=n())%>%
         set_names(c("Cut","Count"))%>%
         slice(match(Order,Cut))
return(df)
})
}
```

Here is another attempt...

```
Fun<-function(df){

Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

Groups<-list("cut","color")

 Groups<-Groups%>%
 map_df(function(group){

     syms<-syms(group)

     df%>%
         group_by(!!!syms)%>%
         summarise(Count=n())%>%
         set_names(c("Cut","Count"))

df<-df%>%slice(match(Order,Cut))
return(df)
})
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to apply `syms` within a loop.  It can take a vector/list of length greater than 1 and convert it to symbols.  Therefore, loop through the `syms` and then use `map` to do the `group_by` on each symbol object

```
Fun<-function(df){

Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

Groups<-list("cut","color")

Groups %>%
       syms %>%
       map_df(~ df %>%
               group_by(!!!  .x) %>%
               summarise(Count=n()) %>%
               set_names(c("Cut","Count")) %>%
               slice(match(Order,Cut)) #%>%                    
               #mutate(Cut = as.character(Cut)) 
               #to avoid the warning coercion of factor to character 


      )




}

Fun(diamonds)
# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   Cut       Count
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 Good       4906
# 2 Very Good 12082
# 3 Premium   13791
# 4 Ideal     21551
# 5 Fair       1610
# 6 E          9797
# 7 F          9542
# 8 G         11292
# 9 D          6775
#10 H          8304
#11 J          2808
#12 I          5422
```

Comment: I like your solution, which worked for the example, but it doesn't seem to apply the "slice" part to my real data. It works if I apply the "slice" part separately after running the function. Do you have any idea why? So far MKR's solution works...but I like the elegance of your solution. Do you have any ideas as to why it might not work in other situations? I know that's a tough question without the data...

Comment: @Mike It is not clear why this is not working with your original dataset.  Could you please check the structure of both or may be use `ungroup %>%` before the `slice`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt at `Fun` works except that the results are allocated to the `Group` variable and not returned. Try the following

```
Fun<-function(df){

Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

Groups<-list("cut","color")

 Groups%>%
 map_df(function(group){

     syms<-syms(group)

     df%>%
         group_by(!!!syms)%>%
         summarise(Count=n())%>%
         set_names(c("Cut","Count"))%>%
         slice(match(Order,Cut))
return(df)
})
}

Fun(diamonds)
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible correction to the problem. For the simplicity I have created a `temp_df` variable and returned the same.

```
Fun<-function(df){

  Order<-c("Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal","Fair","E","F","G","D","H","J","I")

  Groups<-list("cut","color")

  Groups<-Groups%>%
    map_df(function(group){

      syms<-syms(group)

      temp <- df%>%
        group_by(!!!syms)%>%
        summarise(Count=n())%>%
        set_names(c("Cut","Count"))
    })

  temp_df <- Groups%>%slice(match(Order, Cut))
  return(temp_df)
}

> x <- Fun(diamonds)
> x
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Cut       Count
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Good       4906
 2 Very Good 12082
 3 Premium   13791
 4 Ideal     21551
 5 Fair       1610
 6 E          9797
 7 F          9542
 8 G         11292
 9 D          6775
10 H          8304
11 J          2808
12 I          5422
```